# How to determine if a word is a verb besides looking in a list of verbs?

Tags: english, verbs, parts-of-speech

I'm building a PoS tagger and I was wondering if there is a way to determine if a word is a verb other than looking in a list of verbs.

What i'm doing is marking all words as nouns, then if it ends with ed marking it as a past-participle verb, if ending ly then as an adverb, if ending in al then as adjective.

**EDIT: I'm looking to do this in English.**

Comment: I don't know many other ways to do that. But I can add "-ate" and "-are" to your list of suffixes. Your project would be a lot easier in say, Spanish especially, or German. :\

Comment: @khanahk yes, it would be easier in spanish. thank you

Comment: The question is too broad, as it stands. Which language are you focusing on?

Comment: @prash ah, okay. Sorry. I'm looking for English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your goal is POS-tagging, looking up the word in a list may not always be helpful, because the same word may act like one of many classes, depending on its context. (See "[set](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/set)", for example.)

However, unsupervised (i.e. without using annotated data to train a model) POS tagging is a well-researched topic. The paper, "[Two Decades of Unsupervised POS induction: How far have we come?](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/sgwater/papers/emnlp10-20yrsPOS.pdf)" compares several approaches you could use, either for implementation, or for inspiration. As a starting point, I recommend looking into the **[Brown clustering algorithm](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cs4705/fall2012/lectures/brown.pdf)** ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xekYkdJS0aM)), which, despite being one of the most effective methods mentioned there, is simple enough to be taught in introductory NLP classes.

Comment: can you provide me a link to the brown-clustering algorithm-- preferably one in not-so complicated language. I've having trouble finding one.

Comment: @gramme.ninja: done